# Yii rule to disallow specific characters from being validated

Tags: php, regex, yii

I want to disallow the comma (`,`) from passing submission. I know there are ways to allow specific types of characters using the pattern rule, but is there a way to instead specify characters not allowed? The field can contain ANY character just not a comma, so using a regex to state everything that IS allowed would be very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could use the following regex:

`^[^,]+$`

This means there is the beginning of string `^`, then one or more of anything except the comma `[^,]+`, then the end of the string `$`.

This will not accept any string that contains a comma anywhere.